# Recording (voice recognition) with bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition, headset

I try to add feature to my application that you can communicate with it by bluetooth headset.

I have sth like this:

```
BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;
AudioManager mAudioManager;
// Get the default adapter
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
            Log.d("bt", "connected");
            // mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            Log.d("bt",
                    "devices:"
                            + Integer.toString(mBluetoothHeadset
                                    .getConnectedDevices().size()));
            if (mBluetoothHeadset.startVoiceRecognition(mBluetoothHeadset
                    .getConnectedDevices().get(0))) {
                Log.d("bt", "recognize");
                myRecognizer.startListening(); // this starts google voice recognition;
            } else
                Log.d("bt", "no recognize");
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = null;
            Log.d("bt", "disconnected");
        }
    }
};
```

in OnResume in my Activity:

```
mAudioManager = ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE));
if (mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall()) {

    mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mProfileListener,
            BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
    Log.d("bt", "true");

} else {
    Log.d("bt", "false");
}
```

LogCat:

```
bt true
bt connected
bt devices 1
bt recognize
```

It still use built-in microphone, instead of BT headset mic.

Comment: I've been looking into this as well...  I believe this is a bluetooth protocol call issue.  It appears that when you activate a call WITH the headset, then the microphone jumps to the phone.  But if you activate the microphone from an app (not the phone, or the headset) then the microphone used is the built-in mic.  I don't know a way around it.

Comment: Have you found an answer?